# Use of socket_read

Tags: php, sockets

PHP documetation 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php 
says

"
**length**
The maximum number of bytes read is specified by the length parameter. Otherwise you can use \r, \n, or \0 to end reading (depending on the type parameter, see below).
"

Can you please explain this "Otherwise"
I need to read several portions from an application.
Each portion is ending with \0
Still can't get it...

EDIT:
That is how I tried to apply it:
$bytes = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

Comment: You should probably post some example code about what you have tried. Then questions like this wouldn't have to be asked: did you try using the `PHP_NORMAL_READ` constant for the `type` parameter? From the manual: `PHP_NORMAL_READ - reading stops at \n or \r.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function reads from the socket for `length` of bytes or it will stop reading early if `type` argument is:

- `PHP_BINARY_READ` (default) then will stop reading at `\0`.
- `PHP_NORMAL_READ` then will stop reading at `\r` or `\n`.

Appears what you are looking for is the default binary read instead of normal.